# How to detect green from RGB?

Tags: c, colors

I would like to detect green from a RGB. I would like to know if it's green from all variations.

I have a RGB, and I would like to know if it's green. It includes lighter green and so on.

Is there a way?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. Your real question is "what proportions of RGB values can be considered "green" - and is more about psychology/physiology (colorimetry is actually the field name) and such.

Comment: Not only that but it is also culturally sensitive. And language-specific

Comment: Yeah. I get the point. With HSL, I will choose a range. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it to another color space, e.g. HSV or HSL. In those, it is easier to reason about the "color" of a color.

Comment: Even then though, i'd say it's perception. I think from around 47-107 hue is green, but other people might disagree with me.

Comment: @yhyrcanus True. Reminds me of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TtnD4jmCDQ (All The Colours, Including Grue: How Languages See Colours Differently)

Comment: Yeah. I get the point. With HSL, I will choose a range. Thanks.